# Index match does not return the correct value

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, lookup

I want to build a financial model in another sheet (model sheet), for that I used the transpose function entered as an array formula to transpose the values of column E of input-contract sheet in a row into the model sheet. it worked well.

Milestones in Column E of input-contract sheet as, "Effective date", "Payment 1", "Export License", "Kick-off meeting", etc.

Trigger event in Column C of input-contract sheet as, "Contract Registration", "Effective date", "payment 1", "export License", etc.

Milestone date in column E of input-contract sheet (which is calculated based on conditions) as, "1-Jan-21", "1-Jan-21", "22-Jan-21", "5-Feb-21", etc.

now, I wanted to bring in the milestone dates associated with those milestones and wanted to use the INDEX MATCH function. This is what I typed in the model sheet

```
=INDEX('Input-contract'!E22:E52,MATCH(Model!B20,'Input-contract'!A22:A52),0)
```

Where Model!B20 is "Effective date"

I wanted the formula to look for the date when the "effective date" took place which should have been 1-Jan-21. However, the formula returns me the value of 19-Nov-23.

all cells are formatted appropriately, not sure why this happening. can you help?

Thanks,

input-contract sheet

[image]

model sheet

[image]

Comment: Use the third criterion of the MATCH: `=INDEX('Input-contract'!E22:E52,MATCH(Model!B20,'Input-contract'!A22:A52,0))`

Comment: Hello Scott.  thanks a lot, I see now what was causing the error. the "0" was in the wrong place.
Thank you very much